# trigger postback between two aspx pages with change in asp:dropdown value

Tags: asp.net, postback, dropdown

I am having an aspx page with div tag:

```
<div id="report"><div>
```

I am calling other page with the help of javascript function because the "id" decides what drop-downs should be able on page.

```
function loadreport(id){
     $("#report").load('/lists.aspx?id=' + id + ' #reportdropdowns', function () {
     });}
```

In that lists.aspx i am having couple of dropdowns.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Account" AutoPostBack="true"  AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="Company"  AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
```

When i change a value from account drop-down, it is triggering postback event, but that event is coming back to report.aspx instead of lists.aspx.
I thought of catching that postback in page_load of report.aspx and call `loadreport()` using

```
Page.RegisterStartUpScript();
```

Then it has thrown error of "id" not defined. Keeping that aside, whole report.aspx is getting refreshed.
Is there any way, i can do postback to lists.aspx by passing selected value of first drop-down and only refresh second drop-down instead of whole page.

Comment: Because you have: AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: Without AutoPostBack="true", i need to hide a button, then make that button trigger postback, but still that postback is going to report.aspx not to lists.aspx

Answer (score -1):

If you load aspx page through ajax request and assign html to div then all your postback control event will not work with your page that is loaded via ajax request.

To achieve this you have to use ajax request then it will work

Another way to make this work is to do a full page load in an iframe